# CAML Query seems to ignore "Type" in Value tag

Tags: caml

When querying, it seems to not matter what I write at "Type" as soon as I write something.

For example

```
            <In>
            <FieldRef Name='Industry'/>
            <Values>
                <Value Type='MultiChoice'>Insurance</Value>
            </Values>
            </In>
```

Returns the same than

```
            <In>
            <FieldRef Name='Industry'/>
            <Values>
                <Value Type='BlablaCAMLBla'>Insurance</Value>
            </Values>
            </In>
```

What's the point of "Type" then?

Answer (score 0):

The use of type in both examples is invalid and therefore returns the same result.

The type attribute in a value element refers to the data type contained within the element not the type of field. In your example, it would be "text" but if you were querying by a number it would be "integer" and so on.

You can find more details here:

[Value element (Query)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/schema/value-element-query)